# How to set two different useState after res.data

Tags: reactjs

I'm making front end component that will upload the two different images the cover photo and avatar photo of the user. I'm using node.js for my backend with express.js. If the user upload cover photo the backend will send a res.send(image path it defends if the image is coverPhoto or avatarPhoto). But i'm having issue on how to upload both of them in the after the user upload the image. i used to different useState userInfo.coverPhoto and userInfo.avatarPhoto. The problem is after the user click the coverPhoto then click the avatarPhoto the image src of coverPhoto will be broken image.  but after refreshing the image will be there.

```
userProfile.js
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import {
  Container,
  Grid,
  Typography,
  TextField,
  Button,
  Modal,
  Backdrop,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import ImageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Image';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import FormContainer from '../components/FormContainer';
import useStyles from '../styles/style';
import {
  getDetailsUser,
  updateDetailsUser,
} from '../redux/actions/userActions';

const ProfilePage = ({ history }) => {
  const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails);
  const { user } = userDetails;

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userData } = userLogin;

  const userUpdateDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userUpdateDetails);
  const { userUpdate } = userUpdateDetails;

  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    id: user._id,
    username: '',
    email: '',
    fullname: '',
    coverPhoto: '',
    avatarPhoto: '',
    about: '',
    mainAddress: '',
    country: '',
    city: '',
    zipcode: '',
  });
  const [coverPreview, setCoverPreview] = useState('');
  const [avatarPreview, setAvatarPreview] = useState('');
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userData) {
      history.push('/user/login');
    } else {
      if (!user || !user.username || userUpdate) {
        dispatch(getDetailsUser('profile'));
        // if (!userInfo.coverPhoto) {
        //   document.getElementById(
        //     'coverPhoto-file-button'
        //   ).nextElementSibling.style.opacity = '0';
        // }
      } else {
        setUserInfo(user);
      }
    }
  }, [userData, user, userUpdate, history]);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleChange = (level) => (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!level) {
      setUserInfo({
        ...userInfo,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    } else {
      setUserInfo({
        ...userInfo,
        [level]: {
          ...userInfo[level],
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        },
      });
    }
  };

  const uploadCoverPhotoHandler = async (e) => {
    const imgFile = e.target.files[0];
    const imgFieldName = e.target.name;

    if (imgFile.type !== 'image/jpeg' && imgFile.type !== 'image/png') {
      console.log('wrong format');
    }

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(imgFieldName, imgFile);

    try {
      await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/user/profile',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        if (imgFieldName === 'coverPhoto') {
          setUserInfo({ coverPhoto: res.data });
        } else {
          setUserInfo({ avatarPhoto: res.data });
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    dispatch(updateDetailsUser(userInfo));
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, getValues } = useForm({
    mode: 'onSubmit',
    reValidateMode: 'onBlur',
  });

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <Container component="div" className={classes.profileContainer}>
        <Modal
          className={classes.modal}
          open={open}
          closeAfterTransition
          BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
          BackdropProps={{
            root: classes.modalRoot,
            timeout: 500,
          }}
        >
          <div className={classes.modalContainer}>
            <Typography
              component="h1"
              variant="h5"
              className={classes.promptTitle}
            >
              Account has been updated!
            </Typography>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              className={classes.button}
              onClick={handleClose}
              style={{ width: '60%', marginBottom: '2.5rem' }}
            >
              Close
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Modal>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Card className={classes.userProfileCard}>
            <CardContent>
              <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <Typography
                  component="h1"
                  variant="h4"
                  className={classes.titleProfile}
                >
                  <PersonIcon
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      top: '5px',
                      marginRight: '0.2em',
                    }}
                  />
                  Edit Profile
                </Typography>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                  <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      id="username"
                      name="username"
                      type="text"
                      label="Username"
                      value={userInfo && userInfo.username}
                      onChange={handleChange()}
                      fullWidth
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.label,
                          focused: classes.focused,
                        },
                        shrink: true,
                      }}
                      InputProps={{
                        className: classes.textfield,
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                          focused: classes.cssFocused,
                          notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                        },
                      }}
                      inputRef={register({
                        required: 'You must provide an username.',
                        minLength: {
                          value: 4,
                          message:
                            'Your username must be greater than 4 characters',
                        },
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/i,
                          message:
                            'Username may only have letters, number and underscores.',
                        },
                      })}
                    />
                    {errors.username && (
                      <span className={classes.error}>
                        {errors.username.message}
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      id="email"
                      name="email"
                      type="email"
                      label="Email"
                      value={userInfo && userInfo.email}
                      onChange={handleChange()}
                      fullWidth
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.label,
                          focused: classes.focused,
                        },
                        shrink: true,
                      }}
                      InputProps={{
                        className: classes.textfield,
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                          focused: classes.cssFocused,
                          notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                        },
                      }}
                      inputRef={register({
                        required: 'You must provide a email.',
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[^@ ]+@[^@ ]+\.[^@ .]{2,}$/,
                          message: 'You must provide a valid email address!',
                        },
                      })}
                    />
                    {errors.email && (
                      <span className={classes.error}>
                        {errors.email.message}
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      id="fullname"
                      name="fullname"
                      type="text"
                      label="Fullname"
                      value={userInfo && userInfo.fullname}
                      onChange={handleChange()}
                      fullWidth
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.label,
                          focused: classes.focused,
                        },
                        shrink: true,
                      }}
                      InputProps={{
                        className: classes.textfield,
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                          focused: classes.cssFocused,
                          notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                        },
                      }}
                      inputRef={register({
                        required: 'You must provide a fullname.',
                        minLength: {
                          value: 6,
                          message:
                            'Your password must be greater than 6 characters',
                        },
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[A-Za-z ]+$/i,
                          message: 'Alphabetical characters only',
                        },
                      })}
                    />
                    {errors.fullname && (
                      <span className={classes.error}>
                        {errors.fullname.message}
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      id="mainAddress"
                      name="mainAddress"
                      type="text"
                      label="Address"
                      value={userInfo.address && userInfo.address.mainAddress}
                      onChange={handleChange('address')}
                      fullWidth
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.label,
                          focused: classes.focused,
                        },
                        shrink: true,
                      }}
                      InputProps={{
                        className: classes.textfield,
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                          focused: classes.cssFocused,
                          notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                        },
                      }}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      id="city"
                      name="city"
                      type="text"
                      label="City"
                      value={userInfo.address && userInfo.address.city}
                      onChange={handleChange('address')}
                      fullWidth
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.label,
                          focused: classes.focused,
                        },
                        shrink: true,
                      }}
                      InputProps={{
                        className: classes.textfield,
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                          focused: classes.cssFocused,
                          notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                        },
                      }}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      id="country"
                      name="country"
                      type="text"
                      label="Country"
                      value={userInfo.address && userInfo.address.country}
                      onChange={handleChange('address')}
                      fullWidth
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.label,
                          focused: classes.focused,
                        },
                        shrink: true,
                      }}
                      InputProps={{
                        className: classes.textfield,
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                          focused: classes.cssFocused,
                          notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                        },
                      }}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      id="zipcode"
                      name="zipcode"
                      type="text"
                      label="Zipcode"
                      value={userInfo.address && userInfo.address.zipcode}
                      onChange={handleChange('address')}
                      fullWidth
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.label,
                          focused: classes.focused,
                        },
                      }}
                      InputProps={{
                        className: classes.textfield,
                        classes: {
                          root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                          focused: classes.cssFocused,
                          notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                        },
                      }}
                      inputRef={register({
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[0-9]+([0-9]+)?$/,
                          message: 'Numbers only',
                        },
                      })}
                    />
                    {errors.zipcode && (
                      <span className={classes.error}>
                        {errors.zipcode.message}
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        id="aboutme"
                        name="about"
                        type="text"
                        label="About me"
                        value={userInfo && userInfo.about}
                        onChange={handleChange()}
                        fullWidth
                        multiline
                        rows={2}
                        InputLabelProps={{
                          classes: {
                            root: classes.label,
                            focused: classes.focused,
                          },
                          shrink: true,
                        }}
                        InputProps={{
                          className: classes.textfield,
                          classes: {
                            root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                            focused: classes.cssFocused,
                            notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                          },
                        }}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <Button
                      type="submit"
                      fullWidth
                      variant="contained"
                      className={classes.button}
                    >
                      Update
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </form>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Card className={classes.userCard}>
            <form id="userPhoto">
              <CardContent className={classes.coverPhotoContainer}>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  src={userInfo && userInfo.coverPhoto}
                  height="180rem"
                  onload="this.style.display=''"
                />
                <input
                  accept="image/*"
                  id="coverPhoto-file-button"
                  type="file"
                  name="coverPhoto"
                  style={{ display: 'none' }}
                  onChange={uploadCoverPhotoHandler}
                />
                <label htmlFor="coverPhoto-file-button">
                  <ImageIcon />
                  Add Cover Photo
                </label>
              </CardContent>
              <CardContent className={classes.imgProfileContainer}>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  src={userInfo && userInfo.avatarPhoto}
                  height="180rem"
                  onload="this.style.display=''"
                />
                <input
                  accept="image/*"
                  id="imgProfile-file-button"
                  type="file"
                  name="avatarPhoto"
                  style={{ display: 'none' }}
                  onChange={uploadCoverPhotoHandler}
                />
                <label htmlFor="imgProfile-file-button">
                  <AccountCircleIcon />
                </label>
              </CardContent>
            </form>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography
                className={classes.titleProfileUsername}
                variant="h6"
                component="h1"
              >
                {userInfo && userInfo.username}
              </Typography>
              <Typography
                className={classes.profileAbout}
                variant="body2"
                component="p"
              ></Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

Error
This will happen after uploading a avatarphoto the image from the coverphoto will be gone but after i refresh the page it will appear again.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` works diffent from `this.setState` in class components.

when writing `setUserInfo({ coverPhoto: res.data })` you remove all other  fields from `userInfo`.

You need to write:

`setUserInfo(prevState => ({ ...prevState, coverPhoto: res.data }))`

```
}).then((res) => {
        if (imgFieldName === 'coverPhoto') {
         setUserInfo(prevState => ({ ...prevState, coverPhoto: res.data }));
        } else {
          setUserInfo(prevState => ({ ...prevState, avatarPhoto: res.data }));
        }
      });
```

Comment: Holy molly, i forgot that i should used the spread operator. so the previous state will not be change. Thank you so much. I overlook that part.